# javascript - string replace

Tags: javascript, regex

Not sure why but i can't seem to replace a seemingly simple placeholder.

My approach

```
var content = 'This is my multi line content with a few {PLACEHOLDER} and so on';
content.replace(/{PLACEHOLDER}/, 'something');
console.log(content); // This is multi line content with a few {PLACEHOLDER} and so on
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add ' ' around {PLACEHOLDER} :-)

Comment: you need to store the result of replace somewhere : try this : `var content = 'this is {placeholder}'; content = content.replace(/{placeholder}/,'something'); alert(content); `

should work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript's string replace does not modify the original string. 
Also, your code sample only replaces one instance of the string, if you want to replace all, you'll need to append 'g' to the regex.

```
var content = 'This is my multi line content with a few {PLACEHOLDER} and so on';
var content2 = content.replace(/{PLACEHOLDER}/g, 'something');
console.log(content2); // This is multi line content with a few {PLACEHOLDER} and so on
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's something a bit more generic:

```
var formatString = (function()
{
    var replacer = function(context)
    {
        return function(s, name)
        {
            return context[name];
        };
    };

    return function(input, context)
    {
        return input.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, replacer(context));
    };
})();
```

Usage:

```
>>> formatString("Hello {name}, {greeting}", {name: "Steve", greeting: "how's it going?"});
"Hello Steve, how's it going?"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var str="Hello, Venus";
document.write(str.replace("venus", "world"));
```